# Remove left panel in GIMP

Tags: gimp

In GIMP, I prefer simply having a single panel on the right with my toolbox and docked stuff, leaving the left one empty. I realise that I can resize it and just drag it all the way to the left to effectively hide it, but is there a way to actually remove/disable it completely?

I'm using GIMP 2.8.14 in single-window mode.

Answer (score 1):

Go to multi-window mode, rearrange the layout (just the docks, really, not the dialogs contained in them) to resemble what you want in single window mode, then go back to single-window mode.

Comment: This doesn't disable/remove the left panel, it simply removes any docks that were in it. The panel is still there, I want it gone completely.

Comment: Hm... then you get a different result than I. Can you attach screenshots of the previous layout and the one you got now?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ywr1UqP.png It looks like this both before and after. As I said, I can drag the left panel until it's practically gone, and that works, but if possible I'd like to remove it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Go to where the GIMP settings files are stored (in Linux that's usually ~/.gimp-2.8) and find the file "sessionrc". Make sure GIMP is not running, then edit that file: inside you should see a line that reads something like:

```
(left-docks-width "231")
```

Replace that value with 0 and that should make the whole panel disappear. Save, and restart GIMP.

I've tested this with GIMP 2.10, but it should work with 2.8 as well.